# Is there a simplified explanation of how to setup an actionscript IDE?

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, ide, flashdevelop

I've recently purchased some beginner books on basic ActionScript animation and also downloaded the flashDevelop IDE. I've taken a couple Java classes and have a VERY basic understanding of coding and at that, computers in general. I'm having a difficult time figuring out this IDE (eclipse was setup for me). I've downloaded the file and installed the IDE. I made a file and wrote some code but when trying to compile I get some sort of pathway error and also an SDK error. I'm completely lost on how to fix these issues as the results I've found through Google and stackoverflow are not simplified enough. I'm also confused about how this ActionScript code will be turned into, say, a ball jumping around the screen. Could I please get a VERY simple, borderline special needs explanation of how to setup this IDE and also any info on additional programs needed to actually turn the code into an animation? Forgive me for my ignorance, but I'm starting from the ground up and any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: So is it Eclipse that you are using or FlashDevelop? If the latter, have you tried going through the steps outlined in the documentation on how to set it up for AS3? http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3

Comment: I'm using flashDevelop. I've viewed that page and was confused on whether I needed to download Adobe Flash or Flex SDK....or both.

Comment: You might be better off subscribing to Creative Clous and experimenting with Flash Pro or using Flex via Flash Builder. Once you understand how AS works in the context of these tools designed to give you a fair amount of support, then you can switch to FlashDevelop and drop your subscription (if you still want to--FB blows FlashDevelop away as an IDE).

Comment: I've heard Flash Builder is the way to go, but I cannot afford it now. Why is it that I need to download Flex and Flash Builder? More than anything I'm trying to figure out why I need multiple programs to write AS.

Comment: You could *write* ActionScript with a simple text editor - code is just text, after all. You need the compiler/SDK to make it a program. But an IDE will help you with lots of features that make coding easier, like syntax highlighting, code completion, error checking and integration of source code management systems, just to name a few. Also, you can get a trial version of just about any IDE - just try them out and choose afterwards. My personal favorite is IntelliJ IDEA, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for newbies.

Comment: Benign, could you clarify exactly what is your goal? If all you actually want to do is make animation there are other tools available where scripting is minimal or isn't required at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info weltraumpirat. Garry, I'm looking to make some flash games ultimately. I can write the code into flashDevelop and it'll highlight any syntax errors but I really want to see some of these programs in action. I really cannot afford Adobe Flash Builder and I hope they're not the only option. It makes sense now that I need the text editor and then the SDK to compile the code. Is there another program I need for actually drawing the animations? Thanks for the patience.

Comment: The Flash IDE is useful for drawing, but depending on what kind of images you're going to use, you can import bitmap files from Photoshop and the like, or export SWF assets from vector drawing apps. To make the program run, all you need is the Flex SDK, which you can download for free: http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

Comment: Okay great. Things are making a little more sense. I've downloaded the Flex SDK but this flashDevelop tutorial on how to install the SDK is vague to me. Is there a basic explanation on how to do this? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You may try Flash Builder, and you could change different version of sdk in flash builder. http://www.adobe.com/cn/products/flash-builder.html